# Scrollbars overlapping DIVs at higher Z-index only in chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-position, z-index

I have an absolutely positioned `div` with `z-index` defined on it. In this div there is a fixed child `div` with a `z-index` defined on it as well. I want the fixed `div` to be on top of his parent.

In all other browsers this renders fine but in chrome when the parent div has a scrollbar, it appears on top of its child. [Here](https://codepen.io/Raghavan/pen/oELjQm) is a CodePen.

Adding `transformX(0)` on the parent `div` will not help in my case as the child `div` would confine in the parent. Any help on this is much appreciated. I only found [this issue](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/chrome/keq_7veCcpI/yje0EVwwCQAJ) in the Chrome Help Forum but it has not been answered.

Answer (score 1):

Apply z-index using webkit engine. Hope it will fix the issue

```
.abs::-webkit-scrollbar {
 z-index:10;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but adding z-index as mentioned above is hiding the scrollbar, so it looks like if we add any valid style to scrollbar as mentioned above (i tried with just width) hides the scrollbar and user has to fully customize the scrollbar in that case with -webkit-scrollbar and -webkit-scrollbar-thumb. But i need only browser specific scrollbars but doesn't want it to appear over the div. Wanted to also know if it is known behavior or issue with chrome browser.